# Is there a Javascript function to calculate the median of a Set

Tags: javascript

Consider I have a map with Key-Value pairs, e. g:

```
{
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": 2,
    "yes": 4,
}
```

Lets say the map can hold over 1000 objects, and is unsorted. What would be the most efficient way to calculate the median of the values and as a result return the key to the median value?

Comment: please add your try.

Comment: There is no built-in method to find the median of an array or object i JS. You would have to sort the data structure and then find the median from the sorted version.